# Creating custom projections with Proj4?

Tags: coordinate-system, proj

I'm reading into how to customise projections with Proj4 - specifically to achieve tilted projections such as the example below (from [vis4.net](http://vis4.net/))

[image]

The [Proj4 literature](https://trac.osgeo.org/proj/) is pretty heavy going and having explored it I'm not clear which parameters I'd need to change, or whether a custom datum would need to be defined.

Comment: http://grokbase.com/t/gg/d3-js/1342xtbkqt/project-raster-dataset-using-the-satellite-projection

Comment: Exactly what I need!  No surprise Mike Bostock is behind it.  If you want to do an answer along those lines (with attribution) I'll tick it off, otherwise I'm happy to. Many thanks.

Comment: Possibly [Tilted Perspective](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/proj%3Dtpers)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a [tilted perspective](https://proj.org/operations/projections/tpers.html)  projection (`tpers`) using:

- `h`: height (in meters) above the surface
- `azi`: bearing (in degrees) from due north
- `tilt`: angle (in degrees) away from nadir
- `lat_0`: latitude (in degrees) of the view position
- `lon_0`: longitude (in degrees) of the view position

Putting it all together, here is an example PROJ string for part of Europe:

```
+proj=tpers +ellps=WGS84 +h=5000000 +azi=30 +tilt=40 +lat_0=20 +lon_0=0
```

Comment: Strangely, this works in Proj.4, but not in GDAL and QGIS, see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/160792/tilted-projection-in-qgis