# How to create isometric 3D map with postgis

Tags: postgis, cartography, 3d

I am looking for a way to create isometric 3D maps based on data stored in a PostGIS database.

My idea is to create a PostGIS function that will return a SVG image like the one below. It is easy to do for a 2D image using ST_AsSVG and some math to position the map, but I don't know how to "rotate" the map to add some perspective, then "extrude" the contours to add volume. Any help is welcome !

[image]

Comment: For the perspective view you can use [tpers](https://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/proj%3Dtpers) as stated in [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/141493/35047) answer. It comes with proj.4 so it should be supported by PostGIS. For the extrusion part I really don't know

Comment: Do you truly want an [isometric 3D projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_projection) or just 3D? Not trying to nitpick, but those are different things and your example doesn't appear to be isometric.

Comment: This is almost certainly best left to software that's meant for rendering geometry, rather than a spatial database for storing and querying geometry. PostGIS can be used to create a 3D geometry, however.